# How to read blocks of numbers from a text file in C

Tags: c, file

I have a file numbers.dat containing about 300 numbers(floating point,negative positive)in column format. The objective is to first fill in numbers.dat with 300 numbers and then extract 100 numbers each time into another file say n1.dat. The second file n2.dat will have the next 100 numbers from numbers.dat and so on for 3 subsets of files obtained from number.dat. I am unable to understand how the location of the last read 100th number is taken into account so that the file read and fetching for the next block occurs after the previos fetched number.

Trying out the Solution provided by Gunner :

```
FILE *fp = fopen("numbers.dat","r"); 
FILE *outFile1,*outFile2,*outFile3; 
int index=100; 

char anum[100]; 
while( fscanf(fp,"%s",anum) == 1 ) 
    {
 if(index==100)
     {
// select proper output file based on index.
 fprintf(outFile1,"%s",anum);
     index++; }
     if(index >101)
     {
        fprintf(outFile2,"%s",anum);
     index++; }
}
```

The problem is only one data is being written. What should be the correct process?

Comment: A verbal description of this transformation is not precise enough, please post example-files `numbers.dat, n1.dat, n2.dat, n3.dat`. Using 15 instead of 300 samples is sufficient.

Comment: @eznme: The code provided is sugested by @Gunner. Here outFile1 is n1.dat, outFile2 is n2.dat, outFile3 is n3.dat. I have sticked to this notation so as to make it easier in relating with the answer so provided. The poblem is that the outFile1 and outFile2 are just containing one number instead of 100 numbers. Sothe index varaible and the loop is not working. Also, please note that the usual preliminary file operations like open and close have been done but not included above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a program for that as

```
read data from input file line-by-line
keep a line count
based on the current line count copy the line to a specific output file
```

something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INPUTFILENAME "numbers.dat"
#define MAXLINELEN 1000
#define NFILES 3
#define LINESPERFILE 100
#define OUTPUTFILENAMETEMPLATE "n%d.dat" /* n1.dat, n2.dat, ... */

int main(void) {
    FILE *in, *out = NULL;
    char line[MAXLINELEN];
    int linecount = 0;

    in = fopen(INPUTFILENAME, "r");
    if (!in) { perror("open input file"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    do {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, in)) {
            if (linecount % LINESPERFILE == 0) {
                char outname[100];
                if (out) fclose(out);
                sprintf(outname, OUTPUTFILENAMETEMPLATE, 1 + linecount / LINESPERFILE);
                out = fopen(outname, "w");
                if (!out) { perror("create output file"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
            }
            fputs(line, out);
            linecount++;
        } else break;
    } while (linecount < NFILES * LINESPERFILE);
    fclose(in);
    if (out) fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Continue to read from number.dat and write to the corresponding output file based on the index of current number read.

Sample code.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("numbers.dat","r");
FILE *outFile;
int index=0;
char anum[100]; // since we are not calculating, we can store numbers as string
while( fscanf(fp,"%s",anum) == 1 )
{
// select proper output file based on index.
fprintf(outFile,"%s",anum); 
index++;
}
```

Comment: will be highly obliged if you could explain with a code snippet, how to handle the multiple for loops, if to use fread or fscanf etc. Also the file has numbers arranged in column format

Comment: Please see the Edited Question where I have put your suggestion. However a confusion still remains >> After the first while loop exists, how does the second program loop start and continue with the last index stored as we are not mentioning index inside second while loop .

Comment: There is just one loop, where do you get a second loop.

Comment: oh that is a typo error sorry....even if there is just i while loopstill the index logic is not working

Comment: @SKM: again: please post those number-files (in abridged form), a verbal description of what you want to do is not precise enough!